# How should I get all the messages from my database and return it

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a chat app with Java and I'm getting all the messages to a specific chatroom. The issue is I don't know how to put them all in one array or something so it can be returned all at once to the user. I've tried just making a while loop to keep return an array, but it only returns once. I would like to try to just append all the values into one array, but I'm not really sure how to do that. All the examples I've seen, just add existing data like an existing array to another existing array. Please help, I'm not sure what to do.

This is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/get/messages", "xyz"}, method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
public String[] getMessages(@RequestBody GETMessages getMessages) throws JSONException, IOException {
    String chatroomID = getMessages.getChatroomID();
    String sessionID = getMessages.getSessionID();

    String username = getUserFromSessionID(sessionID);

    int userStatus = getUserStatusFromSessionID(sessionID);
    int userChatStatus = getUserChatStatusFromUsername(username, chatroomID);

    if(userStatus == 0 || userStatus == 2){
        if(userChatStatus == 0){
            Connection connection = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;


            String message = "";
            String user = "";
            String timeday = "";
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://HOST/DBNAME", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
                st = connection.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatroom = '" + chatroomID +"'");

                while(rs.next()){
                    message = rs.getString(2);
                    user = rs.getString(3);
                    timeday = rs.getString(5);
                    String combined = message + "~" + "user" + "~" + timeday;
                    String[] returnMessage {combined}
                    System.out.println(combined);
                    return(returnMessage);
                }
                String[] returnedMessage = {""};
                return(returnedMessage);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Expection : " + ex.toString());
                String[] returnMessage = {"Expection : " + ex.toString()};
                return(returnMessage);
            }
        }else if(userChatStatus == 1){
            String[] returnMessage = {"You are still pending to join this chatroom"};
            return(returnMessage);
        }else if(userChatStatus == 3){
            systemReport(username, "Tried to access chatroom: " + chatroomID + " while being banned from the chat");
            String[] returnMessage = {"You are banned from this chat"};
            return(returnMessage);
        }else{
            String[] returnMessage = {"We are having issues verifying you are allowed to access this chat"};
            return(returnMessage);
        }

    }else if(userStatus == 1){
        systemReport(username, "Tried to acces chatroom: " + chatroomID + " while banned");
        String[] returnMessage = {"You are not allowed to acces  the server"};
        return(returnMessage);
    }else{
        String[] returnMessage = {"We are having issues making sure your allowed to login"};
        return(returnMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i got you you can use ArrayList https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html
and for each iteration to use the add to add this string to that arraylist then you use this arraylist to get all the message back
by the way it better to use preparedstatment https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html
as Statement vulnerable to sql injection which is not good from security prespective

Comment: @justsomeone thats for my API the user won't get actuall access to SQL statements just sending data to a url

Comment: what if chatroomID = "\';Drop DATABASE;"; it will drop all your database
of course if your connection has the privilege
better use the best practice even if it education app so you keep it as habit

Comment: its an API they CANT execute any commands read my docs to understand what I mean its not Long docs.anonyomail.com/docs/api

Comment: @justsomeone I just understood what you meant let me test that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You populate a `List` as you loop the result set.

```java
…
List< String > messages = new ArrayList<>() ;
while( rs.next() ){
    message = rs.get… ;
    messages.add( message ) ;
}
return List.copyOf( messages ) ;
```

Remove the `return` statement from inside your loop. Calling `return` ends the loop.

If you must return an array rather than a list:

```
return messages.toArray( new String[0] ) ;
```

Comment: This is unrelated but do you have a suggestion on what GUI lib I should use for my chat application (not javaFX I hate it)

Comment: @FaDeRockYT Yes, that is a tangent, and asking for library recommendations is also off-topic on Stack Overflow. Take that kind of issue to the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. For desktop apps in Java, you have a choice of Swing, SWT, and JavaFX. For web apps in Java, either Vaadin Flow or any of many templating engines. For mobile apps, I have not kept up to even know.

Comment: Thank you sir I just tried it, it worked perfectly I really appreciate the help!